# Printing to Linux CUPS printer from Mac El Capitan - fills error_log and doesn't print

Tags: osx, printing, cups, macintosh

any ideas on this one?
I'm trying to print to a CUPS printer running on Debian from a Mac running OSX 10.11 El Capitan.
When I try to print, my /var/log/cups/error_log reads:

```
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Accepted from [v1.fe80::a65e:60ff:fec1:9b01+eth0]:55661 (IPv6)
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Waiting for request.
I [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Connection now encrypted.
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] POST /printers/HomePrinter HTTP/1.1
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=200
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] No authentication data provided.
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] cupsdSendHeader: code=403, type="text/html", auth_type=0
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Closing connection.
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Waiting for socket close.
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=100
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=100
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=100
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=100
D [12/Oct/2015:00:59:04 +0100] [Client 3] Read: status=100
```

and then fills up the log file with millions (literally) of lines like this until the entire partition is full!

The Mac machine says: "Hold for authentication", but I'm not aware of having requested authentication in the CUPS configuration, so I'm really at a loss.  I can post my cups configuration if that would be of help.

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks,  Julian

Comment: \`code=403`  that's HTTP 403 "Forbidden"

Comment: Yes, indeed, Jasen.  The answer below about IPv6 solved the issue, and the connections are no longer forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too.  In my case, it turned out that a server-side configuration change was required, specifically, in "Admin" -> "Server", enable "Allow printing from the Internet".

Not quite certain why, but it seems that perhaps El Capitan is preferring IPv6 and CUPS on the server-side is interpreting this as an "Internet" access rather than local network.

HTH!

Comment: You're so right!  Thank you.

I'm using CUPS on a Linux machine, so I added this entry to my cupsd.conf file:  
`Allow from [fe80::]/10`  
and now all works!

Comment: @julian-gilbey Where should this directive be included in the cups.conf file?

Comment: @Graham I have it in my Location section, as follows (apologies about lack of newlines - I can't figure out how to put them in responses, so I've written \n instead): `# Restrict access to the server...\n
<Location />\n
  Order allow,deny\n
  Allow from localhost\n
  Allow from 192.168.0.*\n
  Allow from [fe80::]/10\n
</Location>`